# Pythonic Solution for Improving Runtime Efficiency

Tags: python, pandas, parallel-processing, dask

I would like to improve the runtime of a python program that takes a pandas dataframe and create two new variables (Group and Group date) based on several conditions (The code and logic are below).  The code works fine on small datasets but on large datasets (20 million rows) it is taking 7+ hours to run.

### Logic behind code

1. if the ID is the first ID encountered then group=1 and groupdate = date
2. else if not first ID and date - previous date > 10 or date - previous groupdate >10 then group=previous group # + 1 and groupdate = date
3. else if not first ID and date - previous date <= 10 or date - previous groupdate<=10 then group = previous group # and groupdate = previous groupdate.

#### Sample Code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ID = ['a1','a1','a1','a1','a1','a2','a2','a2','a2','a2']
DATE = ['1/1/2014','1/15/2014','1/20/2014','1/22/2014','3/10/2015', \
        '1/13/2015','1/20/2015','1/28/2015','2/28/2015','3/20/2015']
ITEM = ['P1','P2','P3','P4','P5','P1','P2','P3','P4','P5']

df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": ID, "DATE": DATE, "ITEM": ITEM})
df['DATE']= pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'], format = '%m/%d/%Y')

ids=df.ID
df['first_id'] = np.where((ids!=ids.shift(1)), 1, 0) 
df['last_id'] = np.where((ids!=ids.shift(-1)), 1, 0) 

print(df); print('\n')

for i in range(0,len(df)):
    if df.loc[i,'first_id']==1:
        df.loc[i,'group'] = 1
        df.loc[i,'groupdate'] = df.loc[i,'DATE']
    
    elif df.loc[i,'first_id']==0 and ((df.loc[i,'DATE'] - df.loc[i-1,'DATE']).days > 10) or \
                                      ((df.loc[i,'DATE'] - df.loc[i-1,'groupdate']).days > 10):
                                            df.loc[i,'group'] = df.loc[i-1,'group'] + 1
                                            df.loc[i,'groupdate'] = df.loc[i,'DATE']     
    
    else: 
        if df.loc[i,'first_id']==0 and ((df.loc[i,'DATE'] - df.loc[i-1,'DATE']).days <= 10) or \
                                    ((df.loc[i,'DATE'] - df.loc[i-1,'groupdate']).days <= 10):
                                        df.loc[i,'group'] = df.loc[i-1,'group']
                                        df.loc[i,'groupdate'] = df.loc[i-1,'groupdate']

print(df); print('\n')
```

#### Output

```
ID  DATE        ITEM    GROUP   GROUPDATE
1   1/1/2014    P1      1       1/1/2014
1   1/15/2014   P2      2       1/15/2014
1   1/20/2014   P3      2       1/15/2014
1   1/22/2014   P4      2       1/15/2014
1   3/10/2015   P5      3       3/10/2015
2   1/13/2015   P1      1       1/13/2015
2   1/20/2015   P2      1       1/13/2015
2   1/28/2015   P3      2       1/28/2015
2   2/28/2015   P4      3       2/28/2015
2   3/20/2015   P5      4       3/20/2015
```

Comment: Are the ID supposed to be sorted? Or could I have something like `a1,a1,a2,a1,a2`?

Comment: Then do you mind to add the output of `df.groupby("ID").size().describe()` where `df` is the 20M rows one?

Comment: Yes, the are suppose to be sorted before running the code. I neglected including the piece.  See the stats you requested below - it is for a larger file (399+ Million records).

Comment: Will paste stats in a minute

Comment: Here is the stats you requested:  mba.groupby("customer_id").size().describe().compute()
Out[26]: 
count    6.813156e+07
mean     5.858789e+00
std      3.656427e+01
min      1.000000e+00
25%      1.000000e+00
50%      2.000000e+00
75%      5.000000e+00
max      1.067100e+05
dtype: float64

Comment: so most of the ID have 5 entries only and I guess that there is one outlier you need to check and eventually remove. Try this (mba.groupby("customer_id").size()>5).sum()
Anyway I guess we can improve your efficiency working group-by-group. I'll try to have a look later on.

Comment: Without the `previous groupdate` logic it could be vectorial

Comment: An ID could have as much as a 200 entries depending on the time period.  I will try the groupby mentioned above and let you know. thx you.

Comment: Here is the for the results of group by command: 7385

Answer (score 0):

Please don't take this as a full answer but as a work in progress and as a starting point.

- I think that your code generate some problems when you move from a group to the other.
- You should avoid group so I use `groupby`
- I'm not implementing here your logic about `previous_groupdate`

## Generate Data

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ID = ['a1','a1','a1','a1','a1','a2','a2','a2','a2','a2']
DATE = ['1/1/2014','1/15/2014','1/20/2014','1/22/2014','3/10/2015', \
        '1/13/2015','1/20/2015','1/28/2015','2/28/2015','3/20/2015']
ITEM = ['P1','P2','P3','P4','P5','P1','P2','P3','P4','P5']

df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": ID, "DATE": DATE, "ITEM": ITEM})
df['DATE']= pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'], format = '%m/%d/%Y')

ids=df.ID
df['first_id'] = np.where((ids!=ids.shift(1)), 1, 0)
```

## Function that work for every "ID"

```py
def fun(x):
    # To compare with previous date I add a column
    x["PREVIOUS_DATE"] = x["DATE"].shift(1)
    x["DATE_DIFF1"] = (x["DATE"]-x["PREVIOUS_DATE"]).dt.days
    # These are your simplified conditions
    conds = [x["first_id"]==1,
             ((x["first_id"]==0) & (x["DATE_DIFF1"]>10)),
             ((x["first_id"]==0) & (x["DATE_DIFF1"]<=10))]
    # choices for date
    choices_date = [x["DATE"].astype(str),
                    x["DATE"].astype(str),
                    '']
    # choices for group
    # To get the expected output we'll need a cumsum
    choices_group = [ 1, 1, 0]
    # I use np.select you can check how it works
    x["group_date"] = np.select(conds, choices_date, default="")
    x["group"] = np.select(conds, choices_group, default=0)
    # some group_date are empty so I fill them
    x["group_date"] = x["group_date"].astype("M8[us]").fillna(method="ffill")
    # Here is the cumsum
    x["group"] = x["group"].cumsum()
    # Remove columns we don't need
    x = x.drop(["first_id", "PREVIOUS_DATE", "DATE_DIFF1"], axis=1)
    return x
```

## How to use

```py
df = df.groupby("ID").apply(fun)
```

```sh
   ID       DATE ITEM group_date  group
0  a1 2014-01-01   P1 2014-01-01      1
1  a1 2014-01-15   P2 2014-01-15      2
2  a1 2014-01-20   P3 2014-01-15      2
3  a1 2014-01-22   P4 2014-01-15      2
4  a1 2015-03-10   P5 2015-03-10      3
5  a2 2014-01-01   P1 2014-01-01      1
6  a2 2014-01-15   P2 2014-01-15      2
7  a2 2014-01-20   P3 2014-01-15      2
8  a2 2014-01-22   P4 2014-01-15      2
9  a2 2015-03-10   P5 2015-03-10      3
```

## Speed up

Here you could think to use [dask](https://dask.org/), [modin](https://github.com/modin-project/modin) or [cuDF](https://github.com/rapidsai/cudf) see [modin vs cuDF](https://towardsdatascience.com/faster-pandas-with-parallel-processing-cudf-vs-modin-f2318c594084) But probably you should work on how to organize your data before process it. I'm talking about something like [this](https://github.com/rpanai/PyDataSTG/blob/master/NycTaxi.ipynb) it's mine, sorry, but gives you an idea about how correctly partition data could speed things up.

Comment: Thanks rpanai!  I will try and let you know.

Comment: Hi rpanai,
After reviewing your code it looks like the reason your code’s output is different from my code’s output for the second group is because your code is changing ‘DATE’ field.  See original date versus output
A’2 original dates:1/13/2015','1/20/2015','1/28/2015','2/28/2015','3/20/2015' to
A2’s Changed dates: 1/1/2014’, ‘1/15/2014’, ‘1/20/2015’, ‘1/22/2015’, ’3/10/2015’.  Any idea why your code is changing the dates for A2?  thanks again for your help.

Comment: The reasons our results is different is because your code does not enforce the 'or' condition.

Comment: I stated explicitly I was not using the or condition on previous_groupdate. This is nothing more than a starting point. You could check if performancewise it's a road that makes sense and eventually we can work on a full solution.

Comment: Got it,  performance wise 550K records took 22 mins which is better than 1.5 hours I was getting before.  Will run on full set (499M) and post numbers.

Comment: @Pele the full dataframe will be very big. You might consider to split it as on my last link first. Adding multithreading/processing we could get a further speedup

Comment: I agree and will do that since  I ran it on 170 M recs and it ran for 5 hours until I halted it.